# Why doesn't overridePendingTransition work?

Tags: android

I use this function to create animation when switching between 2 activities. But it makes my app stop (not crash, just like pause). I call overridePendingTransition from Adapter in a Fragment of a Activity.

```
public class LessonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<Lesson> lessonList;

    private Context mContext;

    public LessonAdapter(Context context, List<Lesson> ll) {
        lessonList = ll;
        mContext = context;

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lesson_card,parent, false);
        return new LessonHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final LessonHolder lessonHolder = (LessonHolder) holder;
        lessonHolder.lessonName.setText(lessonList.get(position).getLessonName());
        lessonHolder.lessonName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0B8E46"));
        lessonHolder.lessonDescription.setText(lessonList.get(position).getLessonDescription());
        lessonHolder.lessonDescription.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#686868"));

        if (lessonList.get(position).getUuid() == 1) {
            lessonHolder.lessonCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, WordTypeLessonActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                }
            });
        }
        if (lessonList.get(position).getUuid() == 2) {
            lessonHolder.lessonCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, TenseLessonActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                }
            });
        }
        if (lessonList.get(position).getUuid() > 2) {
            lessonHolder.lessonCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, LessonActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("lesson_id", lessonList.get(position).getUuid());
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lessonList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything seems all right, how do you pass the context like this LessonAdapter(getActivity,list) right?

Comment: I have a list of lessons outside, in fragment, I call getContext(). Like this "LessonAdapter(getContext(),list)"

Comment: try to call intent like this Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), TenseLessonActivity.class);

Comment: It is in Adapter, so can't call getContext() :-(

Comment: add the transitions xmls

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling finish() first.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

or supply the desired animation information through a ActivityOptions bundle to startActivity(Intent, Bundle) or a related function

as it recommends in the docs

a stacktrace would be nice and some code from the second activity, also why are you using fragments? Seems like you could do it all in one activity using fragments or not use fragments at all and use two activities.

Comment: post more of your code, you havent given us enough to know what is going wrong I was just guessing at what the problem was